# How to calculate the median of a row, for each row in a large chart

Tags: unix, awk, median

I was thinking awk could do this, I could also use unix or perl if those would work too

Say my chart is something like

```
5 6 3 38 20 3 94 8 20
7 56 3 59 38 20 38 7 13
39 20 2 4 19 20 49 17 20
```

Then I would want it to print the median for each like

```
8
20
20
```

Thank-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ awk '{split($0,a);asort(a);mid=int(NF/2);NF%2!=0?median=a[mid+1]:median=(a[mid]+a[mid+1])/2;print median}' file.txt
8
20
20
```

Comment: When I try this my computer tells me that i'm calling an undefined function asort

Comment: It seems that you don't have GNU `awk`, which is the recommended version. You can verify doing `awk --version`

Comment: You can try using `gawk` instead

Comment: You are right @karakfa, thanks for your observation. I fix it.

Comment: I also get gawk command not found so I guess I don't have gawk